# How do I make a REST api request to the Google Calendar API on AWS Lambda for an Alexa Skill?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-calendar-api, alexa-skills-kit

I am having trouble sending a GET request from my serverless Lambda node.js code to the Google Calendar API. I first tried following the quick start guide from https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs, but the problem I face is that this node module makes my zip file too large to work on Lambda. For some reason, I can only successfully invoke my function when my .zip is small enough to allow Lambda's in-line code editor to run. I have already linked my Google Calendar API credentials and authorizations on my Alexa Developer Console, so I am sending a parsed Google API access token during each invocation of my skill. I'm hoping that someone might know how to send Restful api requests to Google Calendar API without the need of any dependencies, since they typically make my file too large.

Comment: you can upload your lambda zip file on S3 database and connect it to your lambda function for size greater than 10mb.

Comment: I tried that as well, but I still can't seem to invoke my Alexa function.

Comment: This question did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116998/http-request-with-alexa-and-lambda-on-sdk-v2-how-to-make-it-works